# Fire click event on button by code?

Tags: event-handling, titanium, appcelerator

Simple enough just can't get it to work and see no info within the docs. How to fire click event on button by code?

I have tried:

```
btn.fireEvent('click');
```

The button already has an event listener, I want it to run the code within the listener when the app is in a certain state.

Comment: Have you tried given solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to add EventListner to check whether click event is fired or not,see below code ,it fires without clicking the button. you can replace commented if condition with your condition on which you want to fire btn's click event

```
 var win= Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'white'});
        win.open();

    var btn= Titanium.UI.createButton({ title :' fire by code'});    
    btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
        alert('Click event fired ');
    });

    win.add(btn);
    //if(appState)
    btn.fireEvent('click');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after using your code I noticed that the reason the fireEvent isn't working is because the fireEvent I call is two functions deep from the original declaration of the button. I have attempted to add the button to Ti.App.Properties.setObject just after the button is declared then getting the object when in the scoped function. Still doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: Ideally I would like to pass the buttons event listener function to a Ti.App.Properties(unsure of correct datatype) then call the property when in the nested function...

Comment: I am afraid you cannot save UI objects in Ti.App.Properties. Only you can do is to pass this button as window's property and then at that window you can this by  win.btn.fireEvent('click');

Answer (score 0):

I would probably approach this a different way.  You want an application to do the same thing if the button is clicked or if the app is already in a certain state.

```
function doThisThing(){
  alert('This thing happened');
}

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor:'white'});
win.open();

var btn = Titanium.UI.createButton({ title :' fire by code'});    
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  doThisThing();
});

// could also be defined as btn.addEventListener('click', doThisThing());

win.add(btn);

//if(appState)
doThisThing();
```

+1 to adnan for providing the code example to change around.